# AngularJS meteor mongo collection key value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor, meteor-collections

I have this code

```
$scope.users = $meteor.collection( function() {
        return AllClients.find({}, {name: 1, _id: 0});
      });
```

I'm expecting to return a value like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "Samsung"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "HP"
}
```

but it still returns a value like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "SqFP23zTXo6MqDLxP",
    "code" : "A100",
    "name" : "Samsung",
    "address" : "Korea"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "8QtNBoBGrvv5wWpuZ",
    "code" : "B100",
    "name" : "HP",
    "address" : "USA"
}
```

Is this a bug? Or bad coding...

Comment: Try projecting the fields as `var projection = { name: 1, _id: 0  };

    return AllClients.find({},{fields: projection});`

Comment: As @chridam pointed, you need to provide a [field specifier](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers), not just the fields. Your code should be `find({}, { fields : {/* your fields*/}})`.

Comment: Tried this but i'm getting a cursor error....

Comment: If I recall correctly, you'll always get the _id back. `.find({},{ fields: {name:1} })`

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you don't want the other bits of information available on the client side, then you need to do the work on the server side. This is handled using publish methods.

Before all, remove autopublish:

```
> meteor remove autopublish
```

Then you can create  publish method in your server folder:

```
Meteor.publish('clientNames', function() {
    return AllCients.find({}, {fields: {name: 1} });
});
```

This publish method will find all of the clients and only allow the name field, keep in mind that you may still get the _id field, I believe it's always sent.

Then on your client side you'll need to subscribe to it:

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('clientNames').then(function() {
    $scope.users = $scope.$meteorCollection(AllClients, false);
});
```

With meteor, when you access information form the client side, you *only* have access to what the server has allowed you to. In this case, you can request `AllCients` and not have all of the information because the server doesn't allow it.